# selecting rows with id history for a given time interval in one result row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

A table `StatusHistory` contains:

```
ID      Status  DtSince DtUntil    
2415891  0     20200816 20200917
2415891  4     20200917 NULL
2415892  0     20200904 20200905
2415892  4     20200905 NULL
```

I need to select for each id the status for the beginning of each month and the end of it.
The user will input the date needed. For example:

User input --> `@Month = '202009'`

The select statement must return the status for `dates 20200901 and 20201001`

For records that are new and have dtSince>20200901 it should return the active row.For example for `2415892` it should return `4`.

So the result set for @Month = 202009 should be :

```
Id       BeginningOfMonth_status EndOfMonth_status 
2415891       0                         4
2415892       4                         4
```

This is my solution

```
select * from
    (
    select * from 
        (
         select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id  order by dtSince desc) r from  
         dbo.StatusHistory
         where DtUntil  is null or (DtUntil <20201001and dtSince>=20200901) --2432290
        )x
     where x.r=1
)s1
inner join 
   (
   select * from 
       (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id  order by dtSince desc) r from  
        dbo.StatusHistory
        where DtUntil  is null or (DtUntil <20201001and dtSince>=20200901) --2432290
       )x
   where x.r=2
   )s2
on s1.id = s2.id
```

Questions:

1)Is there anything less complex than my code?

2)with the above,i am not covering the `For records that are new and have dtSince>20200901` requirement

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can get all the rows that cover a particular month using a `where` clause.  Then use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows and conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then status end) as beginning_of_month,
       max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then status end) as end_of_month
from (select t.*,
             row_nunber() over (partition by id order by dtsince) as seqnum_asc,
             row_nunber() over (partition by id order by dtsince desc) as seqnum_desc
      from t
      where dtsince < dateadd(month, 1, convert(date, @Month + '01'))) and
            (dtuntil >= convert(date, @Month + '01') or dtuntil is null)
     ) t
group by id
```